# Outlook shortcut keys for "Categories" not working

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have assigned shortcut keys for 4 Categories in Outlook, assigning them to

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>

using the dropdown in the Categories-dialog.

However, none of the shortcuts are working, i.e. nothing happens when I press the shortcuts.

I have tried assigning them to other combinations like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, but with no result.

I'm running on a Danish keyboard, but I have no problems with any other shortcuts.

**Update**

If someone should stumble over this later, the accepted answer below solved if for me in this instance. However, I have later encountered the same problem again. This time the keys were "moved" 5 places up. So the category that should have been assigned using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, could be assigned by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>!

Comment: What type of account do you use? Exchange/IMAP/POP3/...?

Comment: It's an Office 365 Exchange Account.

Comment: Maybe you have some kind of third-party add-in that intercepts these shortcuts? Try to run the Outlook in Safe Mode (outlook.exe /safe) and check if your shortcuts are working.

Comment: Good suggestion, but no luck. Safe Mode didn't change anything.

Comment: That's weird. Ok, then you can try to use these particular shortcuts in other applications. For example, MS Word has build-in CTRL+Fn shortcuts: Ctrl+F2 opens Quick Preview and so on (https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Microsoft-Word-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2#bm4)

Comment: Strange, CTRL+F2 in Words works and shows the Print Preview, as expected. Tried various other Fn-based shortcuts in other Office programs, i.e. Shift-F3 for changeing case in Powerpoint and they all work. Only Outlook and specifically the keys for assigning categories are not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was searching on Google, and then I randomly stumbled upon the answer myself while playing around in Outlook. I'm using Outlook 2010, but I believe it should be the same for your Outlook 2013.

Here's what I did.

1. Right-click the account folder in the folder tree (so not inbox, but the folder in the level above it: ExampleUser@Example.com)
2. Choose Data Folder Properties.
3. Click *Upgrade to Color Categories...* -> *Yes* -> *OK*.
4. Exit Outlook and reopen it.

Your hotkeys should now work.

Comment: For me it’s called `Data File Properties`.