# Outlook Calendar keyboard shortcuts for categories do not work?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2010

For appointments in Outlook, I defined categories with different colors. Every category has a keyboard shortcut assigned. So when, for example, I pressed Ctrl-F12 on a appointment, it turned yellow.
Since a couple of weeks, these shortcuts do not function anymore...

Anyone have a clue as to how to fix this? I tried this, but that does not work for me: [Outlook shortcut keys for "Categories" not working](https://superuser.com/questions/870024/outlook-shortcut-keys-for-categories-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

A similar hot issue for Outlook for Office 365 is also discussed here: [Outlook Categories Suddenly Not Working.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1e968608-48fe-455f-a9f7-778318577021/outlook-categories-suddenly-not-working?forum=outlook) Currently the issue is under investigation. You may revert to a previous version as a workaround.